# In Ruby, why doesn't ternary operator work when using a puts function inside an each statement?

Tags: ruby

Given that you write the code on IRB:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.each {|x| x > 2 ? puts "lower" : puts "higher"}
```

The program doesn't execute the line and it somehow according to the program is an incomplete line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put some parentheses in. `puts("lower")`. Also you're missing a quote.

Comment: You missed a double quote in `higher`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev @Sebastian Palma Even with  `array.each {|x| x > 2 ? puts("lower)" : puts("higher")}`, it doesn't work. Fixed the double quotation marks

Comment: @the12: because you messed up this one too. Look at it closely :)

Comment: Quotes go inside the brackets. Close enough, unfortunately, does not count.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `array.each {|x| x > 2 ? puts("lower") : puts("higher")} still doesn't work.` Lol apologize for the mistake before, and I believe this one is correct!

Comment: @the12 It does work. Try in a new IRB session (or whatever you use to run this)

Comment: As a note, the single most frustrating phrase to hear on Stack Overflow is "doesn't work". Instead tell us the precise error you got, or describe what happened. "Doesn't work" could mean "I got a huge stack trace I don't understand" or it could mean "no output". Being overly specific is usually better than being irritatingly vague.

Comment: @tadman Yeah normally I'd post an error, but there was no error, just an incomplete line, like I mentioned previously.

Comment: @Sergio Tulensev Ok thanks for your help!

Comment: It might be subtle but `irb` usually indicates what sort of character it's looking for, be it a closing quotation mark or bracket.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why do you need brackets though for `puts` in this case? I'm using this as an approximation  for another problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @the12 have you seen tadman's answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by ambiguous arguments. Ruby, unlike many other languages such as JavaScript, is really lax about requiring brackets `puts x` and `puts(x)` are equivalent. Where this breaks down is when it's not clear which are arguments, and which are part of other syntax.

For example, if `f` is a method that takes 1-3 arguments and `x` and `y` are variables, then what is the meaning of:

```
f x, f x, y
```

Is that `f(x, f(x,y))`, `f(x), f(x), y` or `f(x, f(x), y)`? Ruby throws an error rather than presume the wrong thing.

Easy fix is to eliminate the duplication of effort here and use a single `puts` with a ternary used to determine the value:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.each { |x| puts x > 2 ? "lower" : "higher"}
```

Now it works because there's no ambiguity on arguments, there's only one method call so it's easy.

Comment: I get the feeling that every single question on [so] about the conditional operator in Ruby can be answered with (one of) my personal pet peeve rant(s): there is absolutely no reason whatsoever in Ruby to use the conditional operator instead of the conditional expression. The conditional operator is required in C, because the conditional statement is, well, a statement, and the conditional operator is an expression. But in Ruby, the conditional expression is already an expression (duh!), so there is simply no need for the conditional operator.

Comment: `array.each {|x| if x > 2 then puts "lower" else puts "higher" end}` works exactly as the OP expects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag People love the ternary operator because they come from languages like C or JavaScript where `if` doesn't have the same flexibility. Personally I try to avoid the ternary operator in every situation where it can be replaced by an `if` or some kind of guard condition, but 1% of the time it's the least ugly option. When I was primarily using Perl I'd use them a lot because in the land of untamed regular expressions and gnarly syntax full of symbols, the ternary operator is the least confusing part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer explains clearly what is happening.  However you may note that this syntax will also work, but here you are duplicating the method call on both sides of the ternary operator:

```
array.each {|x| x > 2 ? (puts "lower") : (puts "higher")}
```

By wrapping the duplicate method call on both sides, that code is executed on both sides.  But it definitely is better style to do it the more correct way where you are passing the result of ternary to puts

```
array.each { |x| puts x > 2 ? "lower" : "higher"}
```

which is the same as:

```
array.each { |x| puts (x > 2 ? "lower" : "higher") }
```

The `puts` method takes a single string argument and that's what we are passing it.